# Adding escape characters to python string

Tags: python

I have a file name that I want to pass to a program or a bash script. For example if it's `my car's picture.jpg`, I have to change it to  `my\ car\'s picture.jpg` to pass it to os.system like `show my\ car\'s picture.jpg`. Is there a function to do it the backslashes automatically?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: there's [`pipes.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) / [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) -- neither will add backslashes like you want, but both will make the string safe to pass to `os.system`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) module to call shell scripts from Python. Then you don't have to worry about escaping things yourself.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['script_name', "my car's picture.jpg"])
```

`subprocess.call()` will escape everything correctly for you. If you need to read the output of the shell script, use `subprocess.check_output()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass as is and use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), `os.system` is depreciated.

```
c = check_output(["file","/home/padraic/Pictures/my cars' picture.png"])
print(c)
b"/home/padraic/Pictures/my cars' picture.png: PNG image data, 1366 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced\n"
```

To call a script use `check_call`, if you want to pipe you can use `Popen`, there are lots of example in the docs linked above including [replacing-os-system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Comment: I think the *depreciated* is actually *deprecated*

Comment: @BhargavRao, lol yes, watching two screens simultaneously is probably not  good for my grammar.

Comment: You could multithread both your eyes to work on different screens :P

Comment: @BhargavRao, think it is time to call it a night and concentrate on the large flatscreen in the corner ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer several incomplete suggestions that could be helpful to you.

Use `"my car's picture.jpg"` -- double quotes escape single ones

Using spaces in a UNIX file system generates only headaches.  You could pass the filename inside of double-quotes.

```
os.system('cp "my car\'s picture" myCarPicture.jpg')
```

If you are using filenames with backslashes in a Windows system, use raw string

`r"C:\Foo\bah\baz.jpg"`